# javascript phaser 3 animation

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to make an easy game in phaser 3. I have a player class which I call in create function of my gameScene.

Player class :

```
class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
    constructor(scene, x, y, key, frame) {

        super(scene, x, y, key, frame);
        //the scene this game object will be added to

        this.scene = scene;
        //movement speed
        this.velocity = 500;
        //enable physics
        this.scene.physics.world.enable(this);
        //collisions with objects and player fix
        this.setImmovable(false);
        //bigger player
        this.setScale(2.5);
        //fix screen borders
        this.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        //add player
        this.scene.add.existing(this);

        this.scene.cameras.main.startFollow(this);


        this.setVisible(true);
        // this.anims.create({
        //     key: 'walk-left',
        //     repeat: 0,
        //     frameRate: 10,
        //     frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames('playersoldier', {start: 3, end: 5})
        // });




    }
    update(cursors) {
        //controls
        if (cursors.left.isDown) {
            this.body.setVelocityX(-this.velocity);
            // this.walkLeft();

        } else if (cursors.right.isDown){
            this.body.setVelocityX(this.velocity);
        }

        if (cursors.up.isDown) {
            this.body.setVelocityY(-this.velocity);
        } else if (cursors.down.isDown){
            this.body.setVelocityY(this.velocity);
        }
    }

//     walkLeft(){
//         this.playersoldier = this.add.sprite(100, 100, 'playersoldier', 3);
//         this.playersoldier.setScale(5);
//         this.anims.create({
//             key: 'walk-left',
//             repeat: 0,
//             frameRate: 10,
//             frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames('playersoldier', {start: 3, end: 5})
//         });
//         this.playersoldier.play('walk-left', true);
//     }
 }
```

These I call in mz create function in Gamescene file.

```
    createPlayer(){
        this.player = new Player(this, 500, 100, 'playersoldier');
    }

    createInput(){
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    }
```

I just cannot make it move :( there is some commented code, which is not working. And throwing out error that says, I cannot call .sprite etc. When I try animation separately. Without player and controls, it works fine.
I just don't know how to implement it to Player Object.
Any suggestions?
I will be glad for any advice which will help.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found solution. If someone will face this problem.
All you have to do is add `super.update{}`  into update function in player class which you want to animate.
`scene.anims.create({})` is called in contructor itself. In update function, when key is pressed you will add `this.scene.anims.play('animation')`

```
class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
    constructor(scene, x, y, key, frame) {

        super(scene, x, y, key, frame);
        //the scene this game object will be added to

        var klic = key;

        this.scene = scene;
        this.velocity = 500;
        this.scene.physics.world.enable(this);
        this.setImmovable(false);
        this.setScale(2.5);
        this.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        this.scene.add.existing(this);

        scene.anims.create({
            key: 'player-left',
            frames: scene.anims.generateFrameNames(klic, {
                frameRate: 0,
                start: 3,
                end: 5,
                repeat: -1
            }),
        })

        scene.anims.create({
            key: 'player-down',
            frames: scene.anims.generateFrameNames(klic, {
                frameRate: 0,
                start: 0,
                end: 2,
                repeat: -1
            }),
        })

        scene.anims.create({
            key: 'player-right',
            frames: scene.anims.generateFrameNames(klic, {
                frameRate: 0,
                start: 6,
                end: 8,
                repeat: -1
            }),
        })

        scene.anims.create({
            key: 'player-up',
            frames: scene.anims.generateFrameNames(klic, {
                frameRate: 0,
                start: 9,
                end: 11,
                repeat: -1
            }),
        })

        this.scene.cameras.main.startFollow(this);


        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    update(cursors) {
        super.update
        {
            this.body.setVelocity(0);
            //controls

            if (cursors.left.isDown) {
                this.body.setVelocityX(-this.velocity);
                this.anims.play('player-left', true);

            } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
                this.body.setVelocityX(this.velocity);
                this.anims.play('player-right', true);
            }

            if (cursors.up.isDown) {
                this.body.setVelocityY(-this.velocity);
                this.anims.play('player-up', true);
            } else if (cursors.down.isDown) {
                this.body.setVelocityY(this.velocity);
                this.anims.play('player-down', true);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

That's how it looks now and it's working :)